# Blocking, non-blocking and asynchronous I/O

Tags: asynchronous, io, blocking, nonblocking

I've been reading about the different types of I/O and started wondering why operating systems don't just implement non-blocking I/O and emulate blocking I/O through busy-waiting.

One reason I thought of could be the waste of CPU cycles.

Any thoughts?

Comment: One example -busy-waiting: Then leaving a console on 24x7 waiting for user input would use lots of cpu for nothing. If you are a multi-processor with dozens of terminals busy-waiting then no cpu is leftover for anything else. Blocking is much more efficient cpu-wise.  The OS wakes up the dormant process usually via a context switch - or maybe an event or signal (like maybe SIGIO) depending on the OS

Comment: Given how most apps spend the majority of their time waiting for I/O, it would indeed be a waste of CPU cycles. That's really the only reason I can think of. A more pertinent question might be why blocking I/O exists at all -- non-blocking and asynchronous cover all the use cases!

Comment: waste of cpu cycles is really important. for example, when you have a web server, using synch io dramatically decreases you performance

Comment: it's useful to point that, using non-blocking io needs much care about the RAM and for a careless programmer, it may bring vulnerabilities.

Comment: One other point about asynch is that, when you have a multicore system, it is really useful to use threads and with threads and access synchronously.